# WFlutter Firebase- Get only one field of data from firebase document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have a collection of users and in each document, I want only to get on data which is the array, is there any possible way to only get on, or do I need the whole document?[image: Picture of the firestore]

Comment: Maybe you can share your firestore structure? Usually I get the whole document first and then filter it using `user.data().your_array`.

Comment: I uploaded a pic from firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please. Because its a field, as far as I know, we need to get the whole document first. Hope its help you.

```
 await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(your document id)
        .get().then((Snapshot snapshot){
      print(snapshot.data['userCart'])
    });
```

Comment: it works but it doesnt give me the full data

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean full data? It should get all the data in `userCart` though.